# Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors' on local npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I got a problem on understanding how node resolve module in local `node_modules` folder. My app using a module called `http-errors` which is a dependency in `node_modules`. I used a Powershell command to confirm it

```
❯ npm ls --prod | Select-String -Pattern "http-errors"

| | +-- http-errors@1.6.3
| | | +-- http-errors@1.6.2
| | +-- http-errors@1.6.3
```

Why do I still have error on cannot find `http-errors` module?

Add: This is where I require `http-errors`

```
const createError = require('http-errors');

function catchNotFound(_req, _res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
}
```

Comment: can you share where you are using `http-errors` in your js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how node.js resolve modules. Open REPL session and type

```
❯ node
> module.paths
[ 'C:\\Users\\truong\\Projects\\DDAC\\repl\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\truong\\Projects\\DDAC\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\truong\\Projects\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\truong\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\node_modules',
  'C:\\node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\truong\\.node_modules',
  'C:\\Users\\truong\\.node_libraries',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\lib\\node' ]
> require('http-errors')
Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
>
```

Node.js can only resolve modules in those paths. Even npm have that dependency, but if there is no directory name exactly like module name, require cannot be resolved. Read more at [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8).